# Are there any API in twitter Bootstrap for developing bar charts

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I've searched several websites, but have not been able to find any API samples showing how to create charts using the Twitter Bootstrap framework.

Can anyone suggest the correct API to use in Twitter Bootstrap to develop bar charts?

Comment: http://g.raphaeljs.com/ is an excellent library

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Twitter Bootstrap doesn't offer charting capabilities but there are many other charting libraries that you can use.

Firstly, I would recommend using [Highcharts](http://highcharts.com) - it's very flexible, offers a variety of chart types and its very well maintained / supported (if you need it).

Other charting libraries available:

- [jqplot](http://www.jqplot.com)
- [EXTJS](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/)
- [Google Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/)

Comment: Thanks for guidance. This boost my time to go ahead not searching for twitter bootstrap

Comment: Great - there's also another answer in the comments above (Raphael JS - I've not used before). Upvote or accept the answer if your happy :-)

Comment: Would point out that I've had many problems with Bootstrap and jqPlot together, due to bootstrap's reset CSS. Would recommend the other 2, or have a look at options here http://sixrevisions.com/javascript/20-fresh-javascript-data-visualization-libraries/ and **test** them with Bootstrap first!